# Can Adium sort the contact list by log size?

Tags: macos, mac, instant-messaging, adium

Is it possible (via a plugin or otherwise) to have Adium sort the contact list by how much I have interacted with each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=6059)

[This plugin adds the option](http://www.adiumxtras.com/download/6059) to sort your contact list by log file size. The result is that the contacts you talk to most float to the top of your contact list.

[image]